# Why Google Pagespeed Insights is not updating the score after making changes?

Tags: performance, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I have a site. I tested it in Google Pagespeed Insights and it gave me some suggestions. I changed the issues. I deleted some files. But it's still showing the same result and giving the same suggestions. Gtmetrix is showing the changes, but Google Pagespeed Insights is not. Can anyone tell me what is the reason ?
Site Link : https://www.galpal.co.uk/

Comment: What were the changes you made? It is not possible for us to tell you why things are showing up that you believe are fixed without knowing what you fixed in the first place! hehe.

Comment: Okay, please test the site on Pagespeed. Under "
Eliminate render-blocking resources", they is a file "https://www.galpal.co.uk/s/f.php?5c501e.js". I have deleted the file already but it's still showing in the test result. Why it's not updating the result ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the file is still referenced in the HTML.

[image: Showing line 76 where the file is still referenced in the HTML source code]

Because the browser doesn't know that you have deleted the file off your server it still makes the request as you left a reference to it in your HTML.

Even thought the file returns 404 not found there is still a request made for the file. At this point that is something that will block rendering of the above the fold content.

[image: The file specified in comments is still listed]

Remove the reference in your HTML (remove the `<script>` element referencing the file) and Page Speed Insights will reflect the change.

To be clear GT Metrix is wrong here and Page Speed Insights is correct.

**p.s.** - [you should add `defer` attribute](https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2017/12/defer-scripts-to-speed-up-rendering/) (or `async` but that is more difficult) to your scripts

`<script src="yourJavaScriptFile.js" defer></script>`